# angular 2 location.go vs window.location.href

Tags: angular, seo

I understand that location.go will simply change the browser url without reloading the page while window.location.href will reload the page.

What I don't understand is there impact on SEO. My site url scheme is defined in a way that parts of url can be in different order for the exact same page. We dont want to have this as google will penalize it assuming it to be duplicate content. I have two approaches to handle this problem -

location.go approach is more desirable from user experience point. I can load the page and find the correct url in parallel and simply change the url in browser. But I do not know if search engines also take the input from location.go.

Please note that my logic for building unique url is bit complex and require me to go all the way to database. So it makes a considerable difference in performance if I choose location.go vs window.location.href to change the url.

Answer (score 0):

> My site url scheme is defined in a way that parts of url can be in
>   different order for the exact same page. We dont want to have this as
>   google will penalize it assuming it to be duplicate content.

Google does not penalize you for duplicate content (not that kind of duplicate content), so don't worry about this. However, in order to remove all confusion, add a canonical tag to your page and Google will understand it is dealing with the same page.

> But I do not know if search engines also take the input from location.go.

Google is the only Search Engine known to understand Javascript when crawling pages. But, it does not mean it will understand everything about your page. You are better off serving a static version of your page to bots for better/optimal SEO. Don't rely on location.go to have search engines find your pages. Put your URLs in a sitemap.